# Подсказка при вводе в ячейку Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть ли возможность при вводе первых символов в ячейку Google Spreadsheet получить окно подсказок с подходящими вариантами для последующей вставки?
(То есть по примеру того, как это реализовано в jQuery)

Comment: Проверка данных, значение из списка\диапазона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правая кнопка на ячейке => Показать другие действия с ячейкой => Настроить проверку данных. Там в правилах, значения из диапазона или из списка.

Описание на [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=ru&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)